# acts_as_follower undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

In my rails app I am using the gem 'acts_as_follower' I have run the generate command, rake db:migrate set-up the user model but when I go onto my localhost it just says `undefined local variable or method 'acts_as_followable'`

does anyone have any ideas how I could fix this?

Comment: Just in case, did you do bundle install and restart the server?

Comment: Yes I did both of those

Comment: @garbagecollection WOOPS! I always do this! Restarting it worked! If you post it as answer i'll check it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do `bundle install` and restart your server.